# Grails and logback

Tags: grails, groovy, log4j, slf4j, logback

I have successfully replaced log4j with logback in my Grails project, but I'm running into something unexpected that I thought would have been handled automatically.

Basically, there is code like:
    log.info(someObject)

Prior to changing to logback, this worked just fine. Now, it complains about the method signature and ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger wants a String passed to it. I thought this would have happened automatically by some Groovy goodness or who knows what else (that I shouldn't need to care about) by calling the toString() method on the passed object. Is this not intended to be default behavior?

Is there an easy way to get things working without needing to find and change every case of an object being logged? I thought conversion rules looked potentially promising. Would that be the right path to go down?

Comment: Maybe you could inject method to this class at Bootstrap using Groovy metaClass?

Answer (score 0):

Xeon's suggestion worked, though I would love to know if there are other/better ways

```
def methodNames = ["trace", "debug", "info", "warn", "error"]
methodNames.each { methodName ->
    def oldMethod = ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.metaClass.pickMethod(methodName, [String] as Class[])
    ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.metaClass[methodName] = { Object o ->
        oldMethod.invoke delegate, o.toString()
    }
}
```